# Node-LokiJS: not all get requests are fulfilled, request status is forever pending?

Tags: node.js, express, lokijs

I followed this tutorial on file upload with multer-express and then retrieving image by id [Scoth.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/express-file-uploads-with-multer#toc-retrieve-image-by-id).

The setup uses LokiJS as database.

All the API's works fine however when API to retrieve multiple images by ID isn't working for multiple images. Most of get requests are pending on server (status is pending in Network panel of Chrome Dev tools).

The requests never gets completed once in pending state (forever pending) and server gets stuck in that.

[image: Pending-network-requests-chrome-dev-tools]

#### API to Retrieve Image by Id

```
app.get('/images/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const col = await loadCollection(COLLECTION_NAME, db);
        const result = col.get(req.params.id);

        if (!result) {
            res.sendStatus(404);
            return;
        };

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', result.mimetype);
        fs.createReadStream(path.join(UPLOAD_PATH, result.filename)).pipe(res);
    } catch (err) {
        res.sendStatus(400);
    }
})
```

#### Index.ts (All API's)

```
import * as express from 'express'
import * as multer from 'multer'
import * as cors from 'cors'
import * as fs from 'fs'
import * as path from 'path'
import * as Loki from 'lokijs'

import { loadCollection, imageFilter } from './utils'

//setup
  const DB_NAME = 'db.json'
  const COLLECTION_NAME = 'images'
  const UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads'
  const upload = multer({ dest: `${UPLOAD_PATH}/`, fileFilter: imageFilter }) //MULTER CONFIG
  const db = new Loki(`${UPLOAD_PATH}/${DB_NAME}`, { persistenceMethod: 'fs' })

// app  
  const app = express();
  app.use(cors());

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({responseText : 'Server running successfully'})
  })


  //Upload Single
  app.post('/fileUpload', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const col = await loadCollection(COLLECTION_NAME, db)
        const data = col.insert(req.file)

        db.saveDatabase()
        res.send({id: data.$loki, fileName: data.filename, originalName: data.originalname })
      } catch (err) {
        res.sendStatus(400)
      }
  })

//Upload Multiple
 app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12), async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const col = await loadCollection(COLLECTION_NAME, db)
        const data = [].concat(col.insert(req.files))

        db.saveDatabase()
        res.send(data.map(x => ({ id: x.$loki, fileName: x.filename, originalName: x.originalname })));
    } catch (err) {
        res.sendStatus(400)
      }
  })

 //Retrieve Image
 app.get('/images', async (req, res) => {
   try {
       const col = await loadCollection(COLLECTION_NAME, db)
       res.send(col.data)
   } catch(err) {
     res.sendStatus(400)
   }
 })


// Retrieve Image by Id
 app.get('/images/:id', async (req, res) => {
   try {
       
       const col = await loadCollection(COLLECTION_NAME, db)
       const result = col.get(parseInt(req.params.id))

       if(!result) {
         res.sendStatus(404)
         return;
       }

     res.setHeader('Content-Type', result.mimetype);
     fs.createReadStream(path.join(UPLOAD_PATH, result.filename)).pipe(res)
   } catch(err) {
     res.sendStatus(400)
   }
 })

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on port 3000!');
})
```

#### Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fetch Image (NodeJS-LokiJS API) - Example</title>
    <style>
      .photo {
        width: 100px;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        border: 2px solid black;
      }
    </style>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>HTML Example</h1>
    <p>
      JPEG:<br>
      <img class="photo" src="http://localhost:3000/images/1">
      <img class="photo" src="http://localhost:3000/images/2">
      <img class="photo" src="http://localhost:3000/images/3">
      <img class="photo" src="http://localhost:3000/images/4">
      <img class="photo" src="http://localhost:3000/images/5">
      <img class="photo" src="http://localhost:3000/images/6">
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### utils.ts

```
import * as del from 'del'
import * as Loki from 'lokijs'

const loadCollection = function (colName, db: Loki): Promise<Loki.Collection<any>> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    db.loadDatabase({}, _=> {
      const _collection = db.getCollection(colName) || db.addCollection(colName)
      resolve(_collection)
    })
  })
}

const imageFilter = function (req, file, cb) {
    // accept image only
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
        return cb(new Error('Only image files are allowed!'), false);
    }
    cb(null, true);
}

export { imageFilter, loadCollection }
```

Comment: It could be a problem with loadCollection(). Can you please edit your question, and paste utils.js as well?

Comment: @AndrásSimon Thanks for looking into this. I've edited and added `utils.ts` source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a problem with `loadCollection` indeed. 
Remove `db.loadDatabase` from `loadCollection` and load your db only once, in index.ts after you initialised it.

**index.ts**

```
import * as express from 'express'
import * as multer from 'multer'
import * as cors from 'cors'
import * as fs from 'fs'
import * as path from 'path'
import * as Loki from 'lokijs'

import { loadCollection, imageFilter } from './utils'

//setup
  const DB_NAME = 'db.json'
  const COLLECTION_NAME = 'images'
  const UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads'
  const upload = multer({ dest: `${UPLOAD_PATH}/`, fileFilter: imageFilter }) //MULTER CONFIG
  const db = new Loki(`${UPLOAD_PATH}/${DB_NAME}`, { persistenceMethod: 'fs' })
  db.loadDatabase({});

// app  
  const app = express();
  app.use(cors());

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({responseText : 'Server running successfully'})
  })


  //Upload Single
  app.post('/fileUpload', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const col = await loadCollection(COLLECTION_NAME, db)
        const data = col.insert(req.file)

        db.saveDatabase()
        res.send({id: data.$loki, fileName: data.filename, originalName: data.originalname })
      } catch (err) {
        res.sendStatus(400)
      }
  })

//Upload Multiple
 app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12), async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const col = await loadCollection(COLLECTION_NAME, db)
        const data = [].concat(col.insert(req.files))

        db.saveDatabase()
        res.send(data.map(x => ({ id: x.$loki, fileName: x.filename, originalName: x.originalname })));
    } catch (err) {
        res.sendStatus(400)
      }
  })

 //Retrieve Image
 app.get('/images', async (req, res) => {
   try {
       const col = await loadCollection(COLLECTION_NAME, db)
       res.send(col.data)
   } catch(err) {
     res.sendStatus(400)
   }
 })


// Retrieve Image by Id
 app.get('/images/:id', async (req, res) => {
   try {

       const col = await loadCollection(COLLECTION_NAME, db)
       const result = col.get(parseInt(req.params.id))

       if(!result) {
         res.sendStatus(404)
         return;
       }

     res.setHeader('Content-Type', result.mimetype);
     fs.createReadStream(path.join(UPLOAD_PATH, result.filename)).pipe(res)
   } catch(err) {
     res.sendStatus(400)
   }
 })

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on port 3000!');
})
```

**utils.ts**

```
import * as del from 'del'
import * as Loki from 'lokijs'

const loadCollection = function (colName, db: Loki): Promise<Loki.Collection<any>> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const _collection = db.getCollection(colName) || db.addCollection(colName)
      resolve(_collection)
  })
}

const imageFilter = function (req, file, cb) {
    // accept image only
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
        return cb(new Error('Only image files are allowed!'), false);
    }
    cb(null, true);
}

export { imageFilter, loadCollection }
```

Comment: @appu Happy to help. If this answer solved your issue, please consider to mark it as accepted.